# Blow up on PDE: how can I prove that $u$ is bounded in this example?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, normed-spaces, blowup

I am trying to solve the example shown in [image] from the attached article [Ball 1977](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HvDO2fF02ZSbn1ajjHI_Zh2RDVT1iz-j/view?usp=sharing).

Could you please help me prove tha $u$ is bounded in this example?